# Hide full screen navigation when BrowserRouter Link is clicked

Tags: reactjs

I'm setting up a navigation for a react app that I'm currently working on.

I have a full screen navigation which overlays the website when a button in the header is clicked.

I've used useState to toggle the overlay on and off which is working great but I need to find a way to automatically hide the navigation overlay when a page link within the nav is clicked.

This is my Nav component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { NavLink as Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Navigation(){
    const[showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(false)

    let menu
    
    if(showMenu){
        menu = 
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <Link to="/" exact activeStyle={{color: 'black'}}><li>Home</li></Link>
                <Link to="/about"><li>About</li></Link>
                <Link to="/work"><li>Work</li></Link>
                <Link to="/hire"><li>Hire Me</li></Link>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    }

    return(
        <>
            <button className="nav-btn" onClick={() => setShowMenu(!showMenu)}>Menu</button>
            {menu}
        </>
    );
}

export default Navigation;
```

I've tried adding onClick to the links like this:

```
<Link onClick={() => useState(false)} exact activeStyle={{color: 'black'}} to="/">
  <li>Home</li>
</Link>
```

but I just get a compiler error "*React Hook "useState" cannot be called inside a callback.*" So That's me out of ideas.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, as I'm learning React as I go.

Comment: Just call a function and on click call useState inside tha function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useState` has to be executed from a method. Simply create a method and set `useState` inside it.

```
function navigate(){
   useState(false)
}

. . . . . . . 

<Link onClick={navigate} exact activeStyle={{color: 'black'}} to="/">
  <li>Home</li>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out.

I was right with the OnClick listener, but not quite there with the rest.

```
<Link onClick={() => setShowMenu(false)} to="/" exact activeStyle={{color: 'black'}}>
   <li>Home</li>
</Link>
```